# javascript fade in after every use not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The program fades in after the first button press but just displays the results after clicking another button. The fade in only works once, but I want it to work every time the button is pressed.

```
 //1. define the onclick handler
var main = function() {
    var str, len; //user inputs

    //dispatch on button id`enter code here`
    if (this.id == "btn1"){
        //get user input
        str = $("#inBox1").val();
        console.log(str)
        $("#outDiv").text(isVowel1(str)).fadeIn('100');
    }

    if (this.id == "btn2"){
        //get user input
        str = $("#inBox1").val();
        console.log(str)
        $("#outDiv").text(isVowel2(str)).fadeIn('100');
    }

    if (this.id == "btn3"){
        //get user input
        str = $("#inBox1").val();
        console.log(str)
        $("#outDiv").text(strReverse1(str)).fadeIn('100');
    }

};

//2. register the onclick 
$(document).ready(function() {
    //register the handler for all of the buttons
    $("button").on("click", main);
});
```

Comment: Are the buttons hidden? Do they fade out?  Sorry, I'm not understanding the problem...

Comment: I think the problem is that the #outDiv needs to be hidden each time for the fadeIn effect to work more than once.

Comment: The #outDiv is just an empty div.
The buttons aren't hidden and nothing fades out. 
Sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: If you could create a jsfiddle or something, we could help you out further.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9nv8ay6L/1/